# JQuery: Trouble with simple slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, setinterval

I'm having trouble with a super simple slideshow I'm trying to make.  I can't figure out why it won't work.  The first picture shows up but it does not cycle through.

Here is the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cydonknight/kyhxy/

and the JQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval("rotateImages()", 2000   );
        });
        function rotateImages(){
            var $onCurrent= $('#imageSlider div.current') ;


            var $onNext= $onCurrent.next().length ? $onCurrent.next();
                : $('#imageSlider div:first');

            if (!onNext.length )
                onNext=$("#imageSlider div:first");

            $onCurrent.addClass('previous');
            $onNext.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function() {
                    $onCurrent.removeClass(' previous');
                    });


            }

    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: images are not loading in fiddle. not able to try.

Comment: change to this and try setInterval(rotateImages, 2000);

Comment: jsfiddle updated with pictures.

Comment: changes didn't make any difference

Comment: yes. i am trying. bug in this line. $onCurrent.next(); no semicolon here.

Comment: i answered to this post. IS that what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working now. I did lot of changes actually.

your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyhxy/1/)

```
    setInterval(rotateImages, 2000);

function rotateImages()
{
var $onCurrent= $('#imageSlider div.current') ;
var $onNext= $onCurrent.next().length ? $onCurrent.next() : $('#imageSlider div:first');   

if (!$onNext.length )
    $onNext=$("#imageSlider div:first");

$("#imageSlider div").removeClass("current").css("opacity", 0);
$onNext.addClass('current').animate({opacity:1.0}, 1000);
}
```