# Want to toggle between divs so that only one is visible

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'm new to jquery and have written the following code to toggle between content divs for a page I'm designing. I want the three content divs to be hidden by default and then if a header is clicked I want that content div to be visible. I want the divs to close automatically if a different header is clicked so only one is visible at a time.

I thought this code would work but it doesn't seem to be for some reason.

**Code:**

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$('document').ready(function(){

$('#partnersContent').hide();
$('#companyContent').hide();
$('#investmentsContent').hide();

$('#partnersHeader').click(function(){
    $('#partnersContent').slideToggle('1000');
    $('#companyContent').hide('bind');
    $('#investmentsContent').hide('bind');
});

$('#companyHeader').click(function(){
    $('#companyContent').slideToggle('1000');
    $('#partnersContent').hide('bind');
    $('#investmentsContent').hide('bind');
});

$('#investmentsHeader').click(function(){
    $('#investmentsContent').slideToggle('1000');
    $('#companyContent').hide('bind');
    $('#partnersContent').hide('bind');
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='partners'>
    <div id='partnersHeader'>Partners</div>
    <div id='partnersContent'>Information about partners</div>
</div>
<div id='company'>
    <div id='companyHeader'>Company</div>
    <div id='companyContent'>Information about company</div>
</div>
<div id='investments'>
    <div id='investmentsHeader'>Investments</div>
    <div id='investmentsContent'>Information about investments</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work is a very unhelpful description of the problem. *How* does it not work? Does an exception get thrown? Are the results unexpected? What you have now *seems* to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/NAFCc/

Comment: Works for me. This is a crappy test but you'll see that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Jb87v/

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716970/jquery-trouble-with-simple-slideshow/13717320#13717320)

Comment: works for me too http://jsfiddle.net/GjuYK/1/ :)
Where is your jquery script include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your source, and the fact that it did work in my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GjuYK/1/)
I would guess you forgot

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: As I said, I'm new to jquery. This was exactly my problem, not the code itself. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use one Class for all headers - `.tab_title` - and one class for all tabs - `.tab`, like so:

```
    <body>

<div id='partners'>
    <div class="tab_title" id='partnersHeader'>Partners</div>
    <div class="tab" id='partnersContent'>Information about partners</div>
</div>
<div id='company'>
    <div class="tab_title" id='companyHeader'>Company</div>
    <div class="tab" id='companyContent'>Information about company</div>
</div>
<div id='investments'>
    <div class="tab_title" id='investmentsHeader'>Investments</div>
    <div class="tab" id='investmentsContent'>Information about investments</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

`.tab {
    display:none;
   }`

JS:

```
$('.tab_title').click(function(){
     $('.tab').hide(); // hide all tabs
     $(this).next().show(); // show relevant tab
});
```

Comment: Thanks, much neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to `.hide()` contain the string "bind".

The correct parameters for `.hide()` are a string that represents the speed AND/OR a function() callback.

I think you just need to call `.hide()` with no parameters.